# Change empty_label for Django forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm having some problems in changing the empty label for a form. I've read the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField and some pages here on stackoverflow, but I still don't get it. In my models, I have a tuple of counties

```
county_choices = (('county1', _('county1')),('county2', _('county2')),('county3', _('county3')))
```

and the model

```
county = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default='n/a',choices=county_choices,verbose_name=_('county'), help_text=_('County'))
```

I want to be able to override the 9 '-' empty label with a string in my own choice and to be able to translate it. So I imported everything from models and tried in forms

```
county = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Users.objects.all(),empty_label=_("my_own_choice"))
```

and it does not work. I send it the {{ form.county }} variable in my html, but after my own choice, I get a wierd string 'sdadsada dsadadas' instead of my list of counties. Can you help me with that? Do I need to put the tuple with counties within a queryset? What if I don't want to send it a queryset at all?

Answer (score 0):

Create a model for the counties and syncdb. This way you can manipulate and access them with a queryset, same way you do with Users. i.e. queryset=Counties.objects.all().

Look at the [ModelChoiceField documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/) for more help.

Comment: It is correct, but id doesn't help much. I would like to send the tuple with counties. And how do I extract that tuple from models as a queryset??? Btw, love Malaga:D

Comment: It doesn't work, it says tuple object not callable. How do I convert it to queryset?

Comment: Better: create a model for the counties and syncdb. This way you can manipulate and access them with a queryset, same way you do with Users. i.e. queryset=Counties.objects.all()

Comment: I've done that and we have some sort of progress: it fills up with the empty label, but does not fill up the tuple with choices:(

Comment: I have changed the answer, please read it again. Do you have values in the table created for the counties?

Comment: @Alexandru Suciu Any advance?